# String Based Calculator with units and rationals

Tags: ruby, string, math, calculator, units-of-measurement

Given a string

```
7 1/3 inches - 4.12mm
```

What would be the best method to associate the mixed number (7 1/3) and establish the order operations below

```
((7 1/3) inches) - (4.12 millimeters) = 7.17112861 inches
```

My first attempt was splitting the string with operators (+,-,*,/,%) but clearly does not meet the rational requirement. The order of operations is the key but I am lost on how to implement this via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really need to be looking at a proper parser using a define grammar. Something like the lex/yacc solution. I'm not really conversant with ruby but it seems there are some ruby implementations

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/racc/parser/rdoc/Racc.html
http://i.loveruby.net/en/projects/racc/doc/

You can treat a space as an operator which functions like addition. On top of rules for the standard mathematical operators you might have

exp: exp ' ' exp { result = val[0] + val[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) }
   | exp '+' exp { result = val[0] + val[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) }
   | exp '-' exp { result = val[0] - val[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) }
   | exp '*' exp { result = val[0] * val[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) }
   | exp '/' exp { result = val[0] / val[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) }

You will need to add precedence rules and rules for coping with the units of measurement.

An alternative to that would be to implement a [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) which can parse mathematical expressions.

Comment: So we ended up writing a gem that handles the specific use case, parsing Imperial lumber units.  It uses RubyUnits and Citrus for units and grammar. Check it out here https://github.com/burningpony/tape_measure

Comment: One thing I would recommend is having a testing framework. Prepare a bunch of known formula and expected results and use http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit.html this ensures your parser handles as many cases as you can think of.

Comment: Absolutely, we stick to rspec. It's pretty well covered at least for our vertical,  we have to handle quite a bit of bad data, and the gem has been in production since about 3 months after this was posted.  Actually pretty freaking proud of the garbage it will handle. https://github.com/burningpony/tape_measure/blob/master/spec/tape_measure/parser_spec.rb

Answer (score 0):

In order to split the string into its parts without losing the order you can do the following:

```
s = '7 1/3 inches - 4.12mm'

s.split(/(?: |(?:(?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))|(?:(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)))/)
# => ["7", "1/3", "inches", "-", "4.12", "mm"]
```

This code splits on spaces and on the border between numbers and letters.

Now all you have to do is [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) the array, and compute your result